# How to concat two tensors of size [B,C,13,18] and [B,C,14,18] respectively in Pytorch?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, concatenation, conv-neural-network

I often met this problem when the height or width of an image or a tensor becomes odd.

For example, suppose the original tensor is of size [B,C,13,18]. After forwarding a strided-2 conv and several other conv layers, its size will become [B,C,7,9]. If we upsample the output by 2 and concat it with the original feature map as most cases, the error occurs.

I found that in many source codes, they use even sizes like (512,512) for training, so this kind of problem won't happen. But for test, I use the original image size to keep fine details and often met this problem.

What should I do? Do I need to change the network architecture?

Answer (score 1):

Concatenating tensors with incompatible shapes does not make sense. Information is missing, and you need to specify it by yourself. The question is, what do you are expected from this concatenation ? Usually, you pad the input with zeros, or truncate the output, in order to get compatible shapes (in the general case, being even is not the required condition). If the height and width are large enough, the edge effect should be negligible (well, except perhaps on the edge, it depends).

So if you are dealing with convolutions only, no need to change the architecture strictly speaking, just to add a padding layer somewhere it seems appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Instead of padding or truncating, how about upsampling to the original size? For example, save the input size [13,18] and upsample the output [7,9] to [13,18] instead of upsampling by 2. 
I still have a question: when we have a dataset with different image sizes, sometimes an input size already meet the compatible condition without padding layers, but sometimes the tensors become incompatible like the sizes are odd. So what should I do for this case? It seems that the padding layer should only work in some specific cases, which is not a general solution.

Comment: IMHO, at this point it is an network architecture design issue and there is no unique answer. But the idea is to use padding only if negligible, not to pad by half of the input size. In such a case, of course I would rather use upsampling. It is true that if the dimension of the input in inconsistent, padding cannot be used. I don't think there is a very generic way to make sure that the input and output shapes are the same, but I may be wrong. If the input shape does not vary much, You could use upsampling layers as first and last layers specifying the output shape instead of scaling factor.

Comment: Also, don't forget that nothing forbid you to use padding of the input/output under some condition using if/else. At least in Pytorch, the network graph can change dynamically, so you can enable padding when necessary, and disable it otherwise. It is not elegant but it is not terrible either. This way the core network remains unchanged and is systematically used for processing the input, only the padding part is specific.